# How to layout core text emoji?

Tags: core-text

When I input the emoji to the core text and UILabel, the emoji line space in core text different between in UILabel. 
1、The same font.
2、The same Width.
But in core text the line space of contain emoji that is higher than in UILabel. How to fix then.